# SQL - Count and if/ else depending on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: TEMPLATE table with unique email template IDs and the name

| template_ID | template_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | river |
| 3 | Null |
| 4 | phone |
| 5 | tree |

and the STATUS table which shows emails that have been delivered, are pending or failed. It also has the template ID so I know which email template was used

| status_type | template_ID |
| --- | --- |
| delivered | 1 |
| pending | 1 |
| failed | 1 |
| delivered | 1 |
| delivered | 2 |

I want to create a new table that shows:

- unique template ID
- count of status type per template ID (only count if status = 'delivered')
- template type (return 'fra' if template_name is NULL, else 'em')

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inline query` like below.

```
select 
template_id,
(select count(*) from Status s where s.Template_id=t.template_id AND 
s.status_type='delivered') deliveredcount,

case when t.template_name is null then 'fra'
else 'em' end as template_type
from template t
```

Or try below `window function` with `distinct`.

```
select distinct
t.template_id,
count (s.template_Id) over (partition by t.template_id) deliveredcount,

case when t.template_name is null then 'fra'
else 'em' end as template_type
from template t left join
Status s on t.template_id=s.template_Id AND s.status_type='delivered'
```